# Best practice for closing multiple Resources by a single method

Tags: java, jsp

I am very new to Java. Now I am developing a web service with JSP and Servelet's. I had a class called `DBUtil` which deals with databases operations. Because this class serves as a helper class for many JSP pages, I put every function static. One example is the call:

```
  public static boolean isAdmin (String uid) {
   boolean  result = false;
   Connection conn = getConnection(); // Datamanager.getConnection(...);
   PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;  
   try{
       pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select u_admin from table where uid = ?");
       pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(uid));
       rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()){
                result = rs.getBoolean(1);
       }
   }catch(){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
       try{
           if(rs != null){
               rs.close();
               rs = null;
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try{
           if(pstmt != null){
               pstmt.close();
               pstmt = null;
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try{
           if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }            
    }     
    return result;  
}
```

So every static function will open some resources and close it. Now the Problem is that many functions have to close multiple Resourses such as `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` and `Connection`. Some of them even have more than five Resources that have to be closed in a certain order. Hence, I wrote a function as followings:

```
private static void closeResource(AutoCloseable ...resources ){
    if (resources == null || resources.length == 0) {
       return;
    } else {
        for (AutoCloseable rs: resources) {
            try{
                if(rs!= null) rs.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that I don't have to write a tedious long lines of `try`-`catch`-Statements for `rs.close()`. Instead, I can simply call `closeResource(pstmt,rs,conn)` (for keeping every function shorter).

Is this a good practice? Is there any other Solutions for closing multiple Resources by a single function (I was actually looking for C macro like solutions, yet found nothing).

Meanwhile, I also want to ask if my static function way of database operating is a good practice? I don't want to cache object like Conn in JSP pages because there might be some Thread-safe issues. Correct me if I am wrong and naive.

Comment: I suggest you read my blog post [here](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have `AutoCloseable`, then you're working with Java 7 or later. Then, it would be better if you use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead:

```
try (Connection con = ...;
     Statement stmt = ...;
     ResultSet rs = ...) {
} catch (...) {
}
```

Also, for every method that has to execute a statement, it would be better if you pass the `Connection` as parameter so you can reuse a single connection instead of opening/closing it per statement, thus heavily improving the app performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try-with-resources` by declaring resources between `( )` (Java 7+). Between the parentheses, you can declare objects that implement `AutoClosable`.

Here's an example of using Scanner and ServerSocket, which are resources that require closing, and are `AutoClosable`:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(15180)) {
     //use resources
}
```

All resources declared within the parentheses will automatically close once the try block has completed

[Try-with-resources Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)